# Bindable variable not updating with viewstack / swiz

Tags: apache-flex, bindable, swiz

I'm using the Swiz framework and I'm trying to update my viewstack's selectedIndex with a bindable property. It gets to my event handler which updates the bindable variable but the Main app file's viewstack  never realizes it. What could be the issue?

thx

-Mike

================================

## MAIN APP FILE

```
<mx:Script>
    <![CDATA[
        import reg.model.ApplicationViewModel;
        import beyaz.reg.swiz.SwizBeans;
        import org.swizframework.Swiz;

        [Autowire(bean="applicationViewModel")]
        [Bindable]
        public var applicationViewModel:ApplicationViewModel;

        private function preInitialize():void {
            Swiz.loadBeans( [ SwizBeans ] );
        }

    ]]>
</mx:Script>


       <mx:ViewStack id="theViewstack" **selectedIndex="    {applicationViewModel.mainViewIndex}"** width="100%" height="100%">
    <prescreen:Prescreen id="prescreenView"/>
    <login:Login id="loginView"/>
    <profile:Profile id="profileView"/>

</mx:ViewStack>
```

=================================

## ApplicationViewModel

package com.reg.model
{
    public class ApplicationViewModel
    {
        public static const PRESCREEN_VIEW:int = 0;
        public static const LOGIN_VIEW:int = 1;
        public static const PRSNL_INFO_VIEW:int = 2;

```
    [Bindable] 
    public  var message:String = "";

    [Bindable]
    public  var mainViewIndex:int = PRESCREEN_VIEW;
}
```

}

===========================

## Controller

package com.reg.controller
{

```
import com.reg.model.ApplicationViewModel;

import mx.collections.ArrayCollection;
import mx.controls.Alert;
import mx.events.DynamicEvent;
import mx.rpc.events.FaultEvent;
import mx.rpc.events.ResultEvent;
import mx.core.Application;

import org.swizframework.Swiz;
import org.swizframework.controller.AbstractController;

public class PrescreenController// extends AbstractController
{
    public static const START_REGISTRATION:String = "startReg";

    [Autowire(bean="applicationViewModel")]
    [Bindable]
    public var applicationViewModel:ApplicationViewModel;


    [Mediate(event="startReg")]
    public function startReg():void 
           {

              //CODE GETS TO HERE!
              applicationViewModel.mainViewIndex = ApplicationViewModel.PRSNL_INFO_VIEW;

    }


}
```

}

Comment: Anyone? Anyone? Is there common pitfalls I could look for when Binding variables?

Comment: Which version of Swiz are you using? You should consider upgrading to the latest version (I'd recommend Swiz 1.0 RC2 or even the lastest version from [Git](https://github.com/swiz/swiz-framework)). Anyway, could you please post your Swiz config? Is your `applicationViewModel` a Prototype bean?

Comment: Thanks Gerhard. That was the problem but now , of course I'm getting compiler errors:   
1120: Access of undefined property Swiz.   
1172: Definition org.swizframework:Swiz could not be found.

Comment: The package structure of Swiz changed a lot since the early versions. E.g. the class `Swiz` can now be found in `org.swizframework.core.Swiz`. Please take a look at the [documentation](http://swizframework.jira.com/wiki/display/SWIZ/Home) which is quite helpful. There's also a migration guide. In case you are still having problems just ask another question or update this one.

Comment: Have you tried moving the [Bindable] tag?

Answer (score 0):

I got bit by this problem just last week.

Put your `[Bindable]` tag before the other tags.  For some reason the Flex compiler doesn't fold in the appropriate `PropertyChangeEvent` dispatching unless you put the `[Bindable]` tag first.